# How to show jBPM process image within application?

Tags: jbpm

I'm building a web application that utilizes jBoss jBPM as it's workflow engine.

In the admin section, I have built the capability up upload a .bpmn workflow file into the system. At this point the system processes it and shows the user the different work item's, parameters, and sequence flow of the workflow.

I would like to show an image on this screen of the process itself. Is there a way to use the BPMNDiagram attribute of the .bpmn file to generate this image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Designer can generate an SVG of a BPMN2 file.  You can even configure it to do this automatically upon save so it ends up in the kjar.  In the workbench, we use a readonly version of designer to show a process (and annotate it with state).

Answer (score 0):

You could try using  a javascript library to render the image.  The one I've considered is: [Pleus](http://www.pleus.net/blog/?p=2142)

I haven't personally used the library, but have a similar requirement that I haven't implemented yet.

There are probably a few other options if you research on web.